# Unable to create ingress and load balancer in k8s

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have created one load balancer service using the following configuration:-

```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: dealer-service-elb
    namespace: staging
    labels:
      service: dealer-service-elb
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
  spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    selector:
      service: dealer-service
    ports:
      - name: 'http'
        port: 80
        targetPort: 3000
        protocol: 'TCP'
```

and my aws alb looks like this:-

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dealer-service-ingress
  labels:
    app: dealer-service
  namespace: staging
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /dealers-service/v1/health
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: dealer-service
          servicePort: 80
```

But when I checked my ingress using kubectl command:-

I did not find my ingress url:-

```
NAME                     HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
dealer-service-ingress   *                 80      34m
```

Comment: According to this [eks docs on Subnet Tagging for Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html) make sure you have your subnet tagged

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this, firstly it maybe due to not properly tagging your subnets. This can also occur when you exceed the default number of sgs per network interface. If this is the case you can request aws to increase the limit.